# useEffect. Find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So this is my code in my profile actions

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { GET_PROFILE, PROFILE_ERROR } from './types';

// Get current users profile
export const getCurrentProfile = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/profile/me');

        dispatch({
            type: GET_PROFILE,
            payload: res.data,
        });

        dispatch(getCurrentProfile());
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: PROFILE_ERROR,
            payload: {
                msg: err.response.statusText,
                status: err.response.status,
            },
        });
    }
};
```

and this is my dashboard

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getCurrentProfile } from '../../actions/profile';

const Dashboard = ({ getCurrentProfile, auth, profile }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getCurrentProfile();
    }, []);

    return <div>Dashboard</div>;
};

Dashboard.propTypes = {
    getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    profile: state.profile,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCurrentProfile })(Dashboard);
```

and I get this errror "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency:  'getCurrentProfile'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'getCurrentProfile' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback"

Answer (score 2):

As the warning says, you can can include `getCurrentProfile` as a dependency to useEffect.

Also since the `getCurrentProfile` function is being passed as a `dispatch function to props form connect`, its reference doesn't change and hence you need not worry about change in its reference or `using useCallback` to memoize it

```
useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentProfile();
}, [getCurrentProfile]);
```

Note that in the getCurrentProfile function you must not dispatch itself without a condition

```
export const getCurrentProfile = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/profile/me');

        dispatch({
            type: GET_PROFILE,
            payload: res.data,
        });

    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: PROFILE_ERROR,
            payload: {
                msg: err.response.statusText,
                status: err.response.status,
            },
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Also `getCurrentProfile` is already a function, so you can just have `useEffect(getCurrentProfile, [getCurrentProfile]);`

Comment: It still doesn't work. In my Redux devtools It shows the PROFILE_ERROR it doesn't load my user profile/information

Comment: and also it says bad request

Comment: The errors that you suggest are because you aren't passing the correct params to the aPI request in getCurrentProfile. Also note that you are dispatching the function within itself. Please check the update. Remove `dispatch(getCurrentProfile());` from within getCurrentProfile function

Comment: @JmMacatangay that's a different problem, relating to your API request. Ensure your axios GET request has correct URL and parameters

Comment: It is in the right path.  my folder is api/profile then inside my code is /me that is my i put '/api/profile/me'

Comment: router.get('/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const profile = await Profile.findOne({
            user: req.user.id,
        }).populate('user', ['name', 'avatar']);

Comment: if (!profile) {
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ msg: 'There is no profile for this user' });
        }

        res.json(profile);

Comment: From your code it seems you need to pass user.id to the api but aren't passing it in your axios request and hence the BAD REQUEST error

Comment: my problem is kinda weird. i tried to login the first account i have created in my database (mongodb) it returns a success while when I logged in as a different user it return an error :/

Answer (score -1):

I guess that is the error from eslint wiht react-hooks plugin. The error mean when you use a hooks which accept array as a dependencies the plugin recommend to add any variable, function..., which have chance to change each render, inside the hook function to be included in dependency array. So how to fix it?

- You can include the `getCurrentProfile` in dependency array, but make sure you use `useCallback` to wrap `getCurrentProfile` if you define component or a custom hook.
- You can disable the effect of eslint if you wish by

> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>     getCurrentProfile();
>    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
> }, []);
> ```

Comment: already done that and it works with one of the profile i first created. while the other 2 it only returns a PROFILE_ERROR. -_-